# draw lower limit of Area to use as error patch (fill_between)

Tags: python, bokeh

How can I use Bokeh's Area to plot  between two y-values to represent an error? (e.g. like fill_between in matplotlib)

Comment: You should edit your question and include some code of what you tried and what failed. Without any idea why you could not achieve the result you wanted the question is too broad. [Tags should not be included in a question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/186664)

Answer (score 0):

as Anthon mentioned a piece of code would be very valuable.

In general high level charts (bokeh.charts) at current release (0.8.1) do not have a ready to use way of doing what you need.

My suggestion is to use the bokeh.plotting interface to easily to what you need using patch and line. Take a look at the [bollinger](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/bollinger.py) example for some source of inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways is to use patch method in bokeh , for example if you are trying to replicate something like

```
from scipy.stats import binom
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
k = np.arange(0, 200)
for p, color in zip([0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9], colors):
    rv = binom(200, p)
    plt.plot(k, rv.pmf(k), '.', lw=2, color=color, label=p)
    plt.fill_between(k, rv.pmf(k), color=color, alpha=0.5)
q=plt.legend()
plt.title("Binomial distribution")
plt.tight_layout()
q=plt.ylabel("PDF at $k$")
q=plt.xlabel("$k$")
```

In Bokeh 12.3 you can do this using

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
k = np.arange(0, 200)
colors = bokeh.palettes.Viridis5
plot = figure(width=1000, height=400)
for p, color in zip([0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9], colors):
    rv = binom(200, p,)
    plot.circle(k, rv.pmf(k),color = color,legend=str(p))
    plot.patch(k, rv.pmf(k),color = color,alpha =0.3)
    #plt.fill_between(k, rv.pmf(k), color=color, alpha=0.5)
show(plot)
```